# Comparing dates in php in differring formats

Tags: php, date, compare

PHP 5.3.3.

```
$olddate = '2014-04-30';
$newdate = '30/05/2014';
```

Is there a simple way to compare these dates (which one is more recent) without having to manipulate the strings or changing one strings format?

I'm looking for a one or two liner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not compare values as string.

You can use \DateTime object or convert this times to integer (timestamp), and next compare.

```
$oldDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $oldDate);
$newDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $newDate);

if ($newDate > $oldDate) {
  // Your action
} else {
  // Your action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime`, which is smart enough to automatically parse the string in common cases.  According to the [documentation](http://php.net/strtotime),

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateTime` ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)) is preferred to use for operations with time differences

```
$date_1 = new DateTime($olddate);
$date_2 = new DateTime($new_date);

$diff = $date_1->diff($date_2);
```

The above will return DateInterval object, which contains all the information you need([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php))

It is also possible using [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), which just returns unix timestamps of your time.

```
$stamp_1 = strtotime($oldddate); 
$stamp_2 = strtotime($newdate);

$diff = $stamp_2 - $stamp_1; // really any comparison here
```